# Parsing JSON value fields is array or not. ( Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JSON object reply from server with typical [reply] from a serialize function of input form with submit button.
If not array then i would have only one value to check.

```
{
  101:["true","false"],
  102:["true","false"],
  103:"true",
  104:"false",
  105:["true","false"]

}
```

I know how to parse JSON with values with name/values pairs. But question is how to check if particular name value is array or not ?

Any suggestion/solution is welcome.

Comment: please add the result of *"parsing"*.

Comment: `typeof Object` or `typeof Array`, did you try that?